Every operator on a finite-dimensional vector space of dim ≥ 2 has invariant subspace of dim=2
I'm attempting to find a solution for this problem, and have written a proof and am unsure of a few steps, which I will mark. This is for self-study, so I appreciate the feedback. I'm also wondering if there's a more elegant solution, since mine is very cumbersome. Note that the field is either the reals or complex numbers.

Proof.
First, if dim $V=2$, then $V$ is itself an invariant subspace of dimension two. Now suppose that dim $V>2$.
Consider the case when $T$ has no eigenvalues. Then $F = \mathbb{R}$ and the minimal polynomial of $T$ is of the form:
$$ p(z) = (z^2 + b_1 z + c_1 ) (z^2 + b_2 z + c_2 )*\ldots (z^2 + b_M z + c_M )$$
And $p(T)=0$. Therefore for some $k$, $(T^2 + b_k T + c_k I)$ is not injective, ie there exists a non-zero $w\in V$ such that:
$$ (T^2 + b_k T + c_k I) w = 0$$
Notice that the list $(Tw, w)$ is linearly independent since $w$ is not an eigenvector. In addition, the subspace generated by $(Tw, w)$ is invariant under $T$ since $ T^2 w = -(c_k w + b_k Tw)$. So $span\{w, Tw\}$ is an invariant subspace of dimension two.
Next, consider the case in which $T$ has 1 eigenvalue. (This is the case I am most unsure of). If dim null $(T-\lambda I) \geq 2$, then there exists linearly independent $(v_1,v_2)$ such that $Tv_1 = \lambda v_1$ and $Tv_2 =\lambda v_2$. Thus $(v_1,v_2)$ generates our invariant subspace of dimension two. Meanwhile, if dim null $(T-\lambda I) =1$, we first consider the case where the minimal polynomial $p$ is of the form $p(z) = (z-\lambda)^k$ for some $\lambda$. (Note that $k\geq 2$ because dim $V>2$ and dim null $(T - \lambda I ) =1$, and $p(T) = 0$.) There exists a $w\in V$ such that $Tw = \lambda w$. In addition, there exists some $v$ such that $(T-\lambda)(T-\lambda)^{k-2} v \neq 0$, since otherwise it would contradict that $p(z) =(z-\lambda)^k $ is the minimal polynomial. Since $(T-\lambda I)^k v = 0$, then $(T-\lambda)(T-\lambda)^{k-2} v  = cw$ where $c\neq 0$. Now let $w_2 = (T-\lambda)^{k-2} v$. Then $(w,w_2)$ are linearly independent since otherwise $w_2$ would be an eigenvector, but $(T-\lambda)w_2 = cw \neq 0$. So we have that $Tw_2 - \lambda w_2 = cw$ and thus $Tw_2 = \lambda w_2 + cw$ and $Tw = \lambda w$, so $span\{w,w_2\}$ is invariant under $T$ and of dimension 2.
If there is one eigenvalue, dim null $(T-\lambda I) = 1$ and the minimal polynomial $p$ is instead of the form $p(z) =  (z^2 + b_1 z + c_1 ) (z^2 + b_2 z + c_2 )*\ldots (z^2 + b_M z + c_M)(z-\lambda)^k$ with $k\geq 1$. Then there exists some $v$ such that $(T^2 + b_2 T + I c_2)*\ldots * (T^2 + b_M T + I c_M) (T-\lambda I)^k v \neq 0$.
Let
$$w = (T^2 + b_2 T + I c_2)*\ldots * (T^2 + b_M T + I c_M) (T-\lambda I)^k v \neq 0$$.
There is such a $w$ that is also not an eigenvector of $T$: if all such $w$ were eigenvectors of $T$, then $(T-\lambda I)(T^2 + b_2 T + I c_2)*\ldots * (T^2 + b_M T + I c_M) (T-\lambda I)^k = 0$, a contradiction since it is lower degree than the minimal polynomial. Since $w$ is not an eigenvector of $T$, then $(Tw,w)$ are linearly independent. Also, $p(T) = 0$ so $ (T^2 + b_1 T + I c_1)w =0$, meaning $T^2 w = -(b_1 Tw + c_1w)$. Hence the subspace spanned by $(w,Tw)$ is invariant under T, and is a subspace with the desired properties.
Finally, if there are greater than or equal to two distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, then there exists $v_1, v_2$ such that $T v_1 = \lambda_1 v_1$ and $T v_2 = \lambda_2 v_2$. We know that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent and $(v_1, v_2)$ is clearly invariant under $T$.
Apologies in advance for typos. I hope this is understandable. The thing I'm most concerned with is whether I did anything strange with $F=\mathbb{R}$ and $F=\mathbb{C}$ cases, since I had to treat them separately in the one eigenvalue case.
Thank you very much in advance.

I'm not certain, but I wonder if by restricting T to a specific subspace of V, we can eliminate the single-eigenvalue case. Then, a two-dimensional subspace invariant under the restricted T will be invariant under the normal T. Not sure how we construct this subspace though.

Obligatory remark: the statement is wrong in a general field. E.g. there exists an irreducible cubic polynomial over $\mathbb Q$. Therefore its corresponding companion matrix represents a linear operator on $\mathbb Q^3$ that has not any non-trivial proper invariant subspace.

To reduce to the duplicate -- if $T = \lambda I$ the claim trivially holds. Otherwise if $T$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ (which it always does over $\mathbb C$) then restrict to either $\ker (T-\lambda I)$ or $\text{image }(T-\lambda I)$ (choose one that has dimension $\geq 2$) and call on induction hypothesis.  Otherwise the duplicate link holds.

You can use induction to say that this theorem holds for all smaller vector spaces. If it has 0 eigenvalues, you have your proof. If it has at least one, then I think you could eliminate the last part by using the result of the following problem from one of the previous chapters:
Suppose  is finite-dimensional and  ∈ L(). Prove that  has an eigen- value if and only if there exists a subspace of  of dimension dim  − 1 that is invariant under .
Therefore, V is invariant over some W with dim W = n-1. But by induction, there is a subspace of dim 2 in W invariant under T. This subspace is clearly a subspace of V.
